# ¿"Cociente intelectual" o "coeficiente intelectual"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, expresiones, significado

Leyendo [el artículo de Fundéu](https://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/stephen-hawking-ela-teoria-del-todo/) al hilo del reciente fallecimiento de Stephen Hawking, leo que tanto "[cociente](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9anORqL) intelectual" como "[coeficiente](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9e8d8Dc) intelectual" están admitidas en el DLE. En [la entrada de la Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cociente_intelectual) se menciona también que ambas expresiones son válidas. Sin embargo, que el DLE diga que son válidas se debe a que la gente usa los dos términos por igual, manteniendo así la RAE su posición de notaria del lenguaje sin hacer de juez.

Yo siempre había pensado que la forma correcta era "cociente intelectual", y que decir "coeficiente intelectual" era un error. En la propia página de la Wikipedia se hace mención a esto, pero a falta de una cita:

> [...] es importante aclarar que la comunidad psicológica se ha manifestado reclamando<sup>[cita requerida]</sup> como única forma correcta la de «cociente intelectual», traducción literal del término original Intelligenz-Quotient.

A fin de cuentas, buscando las definiciones de *cociente* y *coeficiente*, vemos que los términos no son equivalentes. Así pues, busquemos esa cita requerida: ¿qué dice la comunidad científica sobre estas expresiones? ¿Se debe emplazar a la gente a usar "cociente intelectual"? ¿O los dos términos son válidos?

Comment: Yo en su día leí sobre el tema un poco y no todos se ponian de acuerdo, hay bastante movida con la palabra de marras. En principio era un cociente porque se hacia una división para calcularlo pero han cambiado los test de CI bastante desde entonces y los cálculos son más complejos. Incluso en los primeros CI despues de dividir se multiplicaba por 100 para obtener un porcentaje y ya tampoco sería un cociente. En cualquier caso la lengua no son matématicas y ambas formas se utilizan, para mi tan válida es una como otra

Answer (score 1):

Dado que según [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cociente_intelectual):

> ... el CI se obtiene dividiendo la edad mental de una persona entre su edad cronológica y multiplicando el resultado por 100,...

y que el DLE define [cociente](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9anORqL) como

> Resultado que se obtiene al dividir una cantidad por otra, y que expresa cuántas veces está contenido el divisor en el dividendo.

y [coeficiente](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9e8d8Dc) como

> Factor constante que multiplica una expresión, situado generalmente a su izquierda.

y que tanto la entrada del DLE como la del DPD de "coeficiente intelectual" remiten a la de "cociente intelectual", yo creo que está meridianamente claro que lo ortodoxo es **cociente**.

Y, como comentas, otra cosa es que el (mal) uso haya hecho que se de por válida "**coeficiente intelectual**".

Comment: Completamente de acuerdo con @walen. Es correcto que _cociente_ es una division, pero _coeficiente_ es una relación entre dos magnitudes (o sea, casi lo mismo) y de ahí que en física usamos **coeficientes de fricción, dilatación, etc** (casi siempre con valores entre 0 y 1 porque son relaciones entre magnitudes) pero no cocientes de fricción, etc. De esto concluiría que ambos son válidos para el caso del C. Intelectual.

Comment: @walen: Efectivamente va antes, pero esa definición es una "propiedad o característica de un **cuerpo**". Me cuesta considerar el intelecto como un cuerpo

Comment: La definición de *coeficiente* que sacás de la RAE no es muy acertada, deja afuera muchos sentidos del término. La respuesta está mal. Nuevamente falacia de autoridad

Answer (score 1):

Encontré un [artículo](http://psycnet.apa.org/record/1926-01773-001) que dice

> Title: Methods of expressing results of measurements of intelligence: Coefficient of intelligence.
>
> Abstract: Discusses the efficacy of several modes of expressing intellectual status. Coefficients of intelligence of 2414 Ss of normal and special groups established coefficients as the most valuable mode of expressing intellectual status. Recommends that physiological age and norms appropriate thereto should be used instead of chronological age and norms based on the same. Frequency or rank is practically significant and should be stated. 'Mental-age' and age-difference are unsatisfactory statements of intellectual status.

Conclusión: "coeficiente" es válido.

Comment: No puedes sacar esa conclusión para una palabra en español de un texto en inglés

Comment: @blonfu - El artículo lo encontré con Google Scholar.  El inglés se usa para difundir los resultados de la investigación científica al nivel internacional.

Comment: Pero que una palabra se use en inglés no quiere decir que en español se utilice esa misma palabra, puede significar algo diferente o tener matices distintos en cada idioma.

Comment: @blonfu - De acuerdo; ¿en este caso crees que hay alguna diferencia?  Yo pensaría que coeficiente corresponde direcatamente a *coefficient* y vice versa; igual con *quotient* y cociente.

Comment: Sí, en este caso coincido contigo pero no me parece que ese articulo sirva para llegar a esa conclusión