# Is there a spoken Spanish equivalent of IQ?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, siglas

Primero mi pregunta en español:

**¿Hay un equivalente en español hablado de IQ?**

**Details in English:**

I know that IQ in Spanish is CI for either "coeficiente intelectual" or "cociente intelectual" and that the [Real Academia Española (RAE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_Spanish_Academy) accepts both for "intelligence quotient" (even though I prefer the latter since few would say, in English, "intelligence coefficient").*  If you disagree, check [this](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=intelligence+quotient%2C+intelligence+coefficient&year_start=1800&year_end=2017&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cintelligence%20quotient%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cintelligence%20coefficient%3B%2Cc0) out.  That said, do the Spanish speakers of this world ever use just the initials like English speakers do?

**If this debate interests you, read this [here](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/cociente-vs-coeficiente.608620/).  It is one of the best WordReference threads I've read.*

**Detalles en español:**

Sé que IQ en español es CI para tanto la frase "coeficiente intelectual" como la frase "cociente intelectual" y que la RAE acepta las dos para la

> **cifra que expresa la inteligencia relativa de una persona y que se determina dividiendo su edad mental por su edad física.**

(aunque prefiero este último porque, pocos dirían, en inglés, "intelligence coefficient").*  Si no estás de acuerdo, mira [esto](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=intelligent+quotient%2C+intelligent+coefficient&year_start=1800&year_end=2017&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cintelligent%20quotient%3B%2Cc0).  Dicho eso, ¿hablan los hispanohablantes de este mundo alguna vez sólo usando las siglas como lo hacen los angloparlantes?

**Si este debate te interesa lee ésto [aquí](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/cociente-vs-coeficiente.608620/).  Es uno de los mejores hilos de discusión en WordReference que he leído.*

Comment: Pregunta reciente muy relacionada: [¿“Cociente intelectual” o “coeficiente intelectual”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/24472/1674).

Comment: In fact, the term in English is "intelligence quotient", not "intelligent". If you search for "intelligence coefficient" in Ngram you get some results, the first ones from around 1910.

Comment: En inglés sería muy raro que se dijera *intelligence coefficient* porque no concuerda con las siglas IQ.

Comment: Por otra parte decir CI como explica @Charlie no es lo habitual, yo lo he oído bastante pero en un entorno en el que era un concepto común en las conversaciones, fuera de ahí no creo que se utilice.

Comment: @blonfu por supuesto, estoy de acuerdo, pero eso no quita para que haya textos en inglés que hayan usado "intelligence coefficient" en algún momento.

Comment: I don't understand this question !

Comment: Intelligence Quotient was the way I heard it.

Comment: @Charlie  Right you are.  You would think that English wasn't my native tongue!  I'll fix it right away.  Thank you for bringing it to my attention.

Comment: @blonfu  Sí, pero en ese caso la sigla sería IC, y, no es, pero tu comentario también apoya el caso de utilizar "cociente intelectual".  Después de todo, fue un término acuñado por un alemán, y el término en alemán (intelligenzquotient) más corresponda a "cociente intelectual".  Si alguien no está de acuerdo, mira [esto](http://context.reverso.net/translation/german-spanish/quotient) o [esto](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cociente_intelectual).

Comment: @Erin Maybe it would help you to understand if I gave you more background.  I recently submitted a question to FORVO to have a native Spanish speaker read/record/make available to others.  My sentence had the acronym "CI" in it, so I was expecting to get a sentence with the acronym, but instead, the speaker uttered the entire phrase.  (Complicating matters is the fact that he used "coeficiente intelectual.")  It made me wonder whether or not just uttering the acronym for this phrase was simply not customary for Spanish speakers.

Comment: "Originally, the IQ was a quotient (a ratio):  IQ= MA/CA x 100 [MA is mental age, CA is chronological age]. Today, scores are calibrated against norms of actual population scores" with 100 as the average, or center of the bell curve (http://webspace.ship.edu/cgboer/intelligence.html).

Comment: @aparente001 La fórmula original ni siquiera es un cociente ya que multiplica el resultado de la división (que seria el cociente) por 100

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ha habido alguna que otra pregunta similar en este sitio, acerca del uso en el español de términos que en inglés se suelen decir con siglas. En términos generales, los hispanohablantes usamos las siglas mucho menos que los angloparlantes (salvo en determinados ámbitos como la informática, que ahí nos encantan las siglas).

Así, yo no le diría a alguien que "voy a hacer un test para averiguar mi CI". Me sonaría raro y además no estaría seguro de si la otra persona me iba a entender, dado que "CI" no es una abreviatura de uso común. Así, le diría "para averiguar mi cociente/coeficiente intelectual".

Incluso si nos vamos al ámbito periodístico, los textos usan las iniciales pero siempre habiendo introducido el desarrollo completo del término previamente; así lo recomienda, por ejemplo, [la Fundéu](https://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/siglas-y-acronimos-claves-de-redaccion/) en el caso de acrónimos no asentados en el lenguaje ([gracias, Alex](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/25662/is-there-a-spoken-spanish-equivalent-of-iq/25663?noredirect=1#comment41860_25663)). Véase el siguiente ejemplo:

> *Pasemos ahora a examinar la situación de los intentos, repetidos a lo largo de los últimos cincuenta años, de dividir la variación del cociente intelectual (CI) en fracciones atribuibles separadamente a causas hereditarias y ambientales. Estos estudios sólo adquirieron trascendencia a partir de la publicación del tan traído y llevado artículo de Jensen (1969), en el que se propone la determinación predominantemente genética de las diferencias inter e intraraciales del CI, insistiendo en la superfluidad de cualquier tentativa de atenuarlas por su condición de empresa contra natura.*
>
> Carlos López-Fanjul, "Vaivenes de la genética de poblaciones [Historia de la Genética]", 1987 (España).

Nótese cómo empieza introduciendo el concepto para luego pasar a usar las iniciales. Y aunque es cierto que este texto tiene más de 30 años, en este tiempo la cosa no ha variado:

> *Meier ha explicado que si bien los 8 puntos de deterioro en el cociente intelectual (CI) pueden no parecer demasiado, la pérdida sí es significativa.*
>
> *Vanguardia.com*, "El consumo de marihuana en la adolescencia daña la inteligencia", 2012 (Colombia).

Comment: Iva a empezar mi respuesta con lo que la fundeu publico sobre acrónimos y terminar con un ejemplo sobre su uso en los medios. "Se recomienda traducir las siglas extranjeras (UNO-ONU), salvo que se trate de siglas que ya estén asentadas en el uso, correspondan a nombres comerciales o presenten dificultades de traducción: IBM permanece en inglés[...]se aconseja indicar la primera vez que se escriba una sigla no muy difundida las palabras a las que corresponde[...]o bien escribir primero el nombre completo y poner después la sigla entre paréntesis" CI no esta asentada ni de forma escrita ni oral.

Comment: Si os animais a leerlo: https://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/siglas-traduccion/ y https://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/siglas-y-acronimos-claves-de-redaccion/

Comment: Charlie, voy a otorgarte la marca verde por tu respuesta, pero una virtual marca verde va a @AlexBcn.  Sus comentarios especialmente esa parte sobre "CI no está asentada ni de forma escrita ni oral."  Ese pedazito fue muy, muy útil (y sorprendente al mismo tiempo).  Pero laureles va a ti también, Charlie, si, para nada más, el enlace a Fundéu.  Es una fuente de información que ha estado perdido de mi vida.  Mil gracias.